# Regular expression passes number in the first byte

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to check to make sure a variable name starts only with alphabet and trying the below code to do it,

But for some reason it's failing

```
>>> a='1'
>>> if re.search(r"/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*$/",a):
...     print 'pass'
... else:
...     print 'fail'
...
fail
>>>
```

I need to make sure the first alphabet is not numeric and following characters are only letters, `a-z`, `0-9` and underscore `_`

Comment: Your example doesn't make sense, because according to your description that example *should* fail, since it doesn't start with a letter.

Comment: Right, swap the pass and fail conditions?

Comment: This regex `"^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*$"` will work as expected: it will match for strings that start with an ASCII letter, and won't match when the first character is anything but an ASCII letter.

Comment: isn't `re.match` better to do that?

Comment: I do a whole match on the string..ie;checking for 1st byte as well other bytes..Do you see any downside?

Answer (score 3):

Don't include those slashes in your regex.  The string should contain just the actual regex you want to match.  (In Perl the slashes are used to delimit the regex, but in Python the string quotes delimit it.)  Your regex will never match because it tries to match beginning-of-line (`^`) right after a slash.

Comment: @user1050619: Then update your question to show your current code and current error.